# How find the longest consecutive path in a binary tree

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, tree, binary-tree

I was asked in an interview this question. Consider a binary tree, we need to print the length of the longest path, where each element differs by 1.

EG:

```
          6
        /   \  
      5       7
     / \     / \
    2   4   8   9
```

answer: 5
( 4,5,6,7,8 )

How to do this?
I developed an algoirthm to print increasing path from root to leaf, but I was not to develop one that keeps track of path that's on both subtrees.

**EDIT**: Need to get back the original tree after modification.

Comment: Modifying the tree and the keeping track of it to get the original tree back is silly. Instead, skip traveling those sections of the tree where difference is more than one by checking whether `Math.Abs(node.value - parent.value) > 1`. If that is true, there is no point in traveling down that path.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As suggested by @qwertyman in the comments

1. remove all invalid edges i.e edges whose difference is greater than 1
2. Now we have a forest, for each forest calculate the diameter as it is given in @Filip Kočica solution
3. The answer would be the max diameter out of all forests

Comment: how to get the original tree back

Comment: Just store the invalid edges in a data structure and add them back later on

Answer (score 1):

For each subtree, you can calculate the longest increasing path down from the subtree root, the longest decreasing path down, and the longest internal path consisting of the increasing and decreasing paths down from the same node anywhere in the subtree.

It's easy to calculate these for a node if you already have them for all of its children, so you can do it as part of any postorder traversal.

The answer is the longest internal path within the whole tree.

Answer (score 1):

<sub>The answer is incorrect - another user correctly pointed out a bug. My solution below works only when the max length path passes through the root. In case, for example, the max length path is entirely in the left subtree and does not pass through the root, this answer fails. Feel free to read further to acquaint yourself with a recursive solution... and the bug in it.</sub>

---

I'm assuming that it is not important that the path has to have a difference of +1 as shown in your example. A difference of -1, resulting in a path like `4 -> 5 -> 4 -> 3 -> 4 -> 5` is ok as well.

```
public int getLongestConsecutivePath(TreeNode root) {
    return root == null
        ? 0
        : getLength(root.left, root.value) + getLength(root.right, root.value);
}

private int getLength(TreeNode node, int prevVal) {
    return node == null || Math.abs(node.value - prevVal) > 1
        ? 0
        : Math.max(getLength(node.left, node.value), getLength(node.right, node.value)) + 1;
}
```

**Explanation:**

- If the root is not null, we get the max length in left and right subtree and sum it.
- To get max length in a subtree, we recursively get the max length of right and left subtree of the subtree.

  - If we have reached the leaf OR if we have reached a node where the difference in value is greater than 1, we return 0.
  - Else we recursively get the max length from the left and right subtree and add 1 to it to accommodate for this node itself.

Comment: you are adding root getLength left side and right side but suppose root node value doesn't differ from left and right node by 1 then your solution will be buggy.

Comment: @nomanpouigt: If the left (and/or right) child do not have a value difference of 1 from root node's value, then `getLength()` will return 0, which is correct because the only path available for traversal from root to its child, in this case, is not valid. (Are you assuming that a single node means a path of length 1? I'm assuming that for a path of length 1, you would need 2 nodes.)

Comment: what happens in the case when root and root.left doesn't have a difference of 1 but maximum consecutive path lies in the root.left but in your code you will ignore it completely as you will pass getLength(root.right).

Comment: @nomanpouigt: You are correct. The max length path may not be through the root. I'll edit my answer and mention the bug. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Let `longest_desc[a]` be the longest 1-by-1 descending path going down from a
Similarly `longest_asc[a]`, the longest 1-by-1 incremental path going down from a

For a fixed root R, the answer would be `longest_desc[R] + longest_asc[R] - 1`.

A brut force solution would do 2 dfs/bfs traversals from each node X to compute `longest_asc[X] and longest_desc[X]` and then merge them together. The resulting runtime complexity would be `O(n^2)`.

But we can actually do better using dynamic programming:

```
longest_asc[X] = max(longest_asc[Y in children[X]] with Y = X + 1)
longest_desc[X] = max(longest_desc[Y in children[X]] with Y = X - 1)
```

Then we can compute all the values in a single DFS traversal => `O(n)` solution.